# How get id off button in laravel controller laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

Here i have buttons like this

```
<button type="submit" name="submit_1" class="btn green" value="submit_1">Save & Add Another</button>
<button type="submit" name="submit_1" class="btn green" value="submit_2">Save & Exit</button>
```

in my controller i redirect pages on button click i cannot change name of buttons because i am using in update function to redirect with **submit_1**
now what should do i also can use id maybe for this but dont know how to use it

```
if(Input::get('submit_1')) {
        return redirect()->route('data.create');
    } elseif(Input::get('')) {
        return redirect()->route('data.index');
    }
```

Its always redirect to create page but i want if i click **button2** which is **Save & Exit** it should be redirect to index page.
what should i do to to differentiate between buttons except changing name of buttons.. if any method with id please help me and guide to best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compare the input with a value.

At the minute your basically just saying `if('submit_1')` (or 'submit_2') either will evaluate to being `true`, you're not actually checking the the value for `submit_1` is actually 'submit_1'.

(I think the confusion comes from having the value of one of your buttons being the same as the name of your buttons )

Change your if condition to be:

```
if(Input::get('submit_1') == 'submit_1')
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should look for the value of the submit_1 button.

```
if(Input::get('submit_1') == "submit_1") {
    return redirect()->route('data.create');
} else if(Input::get('submit_1') == "submit_2") {
    return redirect()->route('data.index');
}
```

However giving same name to 2 different buttons is not a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

first set id in your button.
lets say id 1 and id 2
In this case route call in your button should be like..

```
<a href="[your route]" id=1 class="btn green">
```

And in your routs it should be like

```
Route::get('[your link to be displayed]{id?}', 'Controller@action')
```

In th function call it should be like

```
 public function action($id = null) {

   if($id=1) {
       return redirect()->route('data.create');
 } 
   elseif($id=2) {
    return redirect()->route('data.index');
}
```

}

Hope this would be usefull